# The completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ (baby Rudin 3.25)

Tags: real-analysis, complete-spaces

> *Exercise 3.25* Let $X$ be a metric space whose points are the rational numbers, with metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$. What is the completion of this space?

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ - which is complete - my take is that the completion of the space described in the exercise is in fact $\mathbb{R}$. The problem is this "answer" doesn't even mention the metric proposed by the exercise. I don't think it's relevant because, well, this *is* the metric of $\mathbb{R}$, but I think I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right: $\Bbb R$ is the completion of $\Bbb Q$ under the standard metric.
The only thing you might be missing here is that the metric $d$ on $\Bbb Q$
is the restriction of the usual metric on $\Bbb R$, under which $\Bbb R$
is known to be complete. In general if you have metric spaces $X\subset Y$
with $Y$ complete, and $X$ dense in $Y$, then $Y$ is the completion of $X$
(as long as the metric of $X$ is the restriction of the metric of $Y$).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on a metric in a space being a restriction of a metric in another space?

Comment: It's just that if $d$ is the metric on $X$ and $d'$ on $Y$, then $d(x_1,x_2)=d'(x_1,x_2)$, for $x_1,x_2\in X$.